# Get data from a mysql database to use in jquery-ui autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an input form and I need to populate the autocomplete with data from a database. My approach seems to be working BUT I am pretty sure it's not the most efricient way. (I'm new to php, javascript)
Here's my code:

```
//get all organizations
$org_array = '';
$sql = "SELECT id, name FROM organizations";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (count($results) > 0) {
foreach ($results as $row) {
    $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM organizations WHERE id = :id";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $id = $row['id'];
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $org_id = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //echo $org_id['name'];
    $org_array = $org_array . '"' . $org_id['name'] . '",';
}
}
```

And here is the JS part:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control autocompleteOrgs" name="newOrganization" id="newOrganization" aria-describedby="newOrganizationHelp" value="<?php echo 
$my_profile['organization']; ?>">

<script>
$(function() {
  var orgTags = [<?php echo $org_array ?>];
  $(".autocompleteOrgs").autocomplete({
    source: orgTags
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: If the code works and you just want to know if there is a better way, you should post it in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to fetch organizations one more time, better approach would be:

```
$org_array = '';
$sql = "SELECT id, name FROM organizations";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (count($results) > 0) {
    $org_array = implode(',', array_column($results, 'name'));
}
```